# How to disable the Firefox image modifying operations for a contentEditable DIV?

Tags: jquery-ui, firefox, rte

I have a js fiddle here - http://jsfiddle.net/stevea/P9Wcr/1/ - with a DIV that I've made contentEditable and that contains an image.

```
<div id='box' contentEditable="TRUE">
    <img src="http://s20.postimg.org/fpitivjl9/Pelican.jpg" width=150px; />
    Here's some text for the box so we can see how text interacts with the image.
</div>
```

I notice that for Firefox contentEditable lets the user click on the image to bring up handles for it, which allow the image to be resized.  Or after clicking on the image you can drag it to another place in the container, and if you hold down the control key while you drag, you create a copy of the image, so now you have two images in the DIV.

I need to have the DIV be contentEditable but I don't want to allow any of the above operations on the image, since my application already makes the image resizable and draggable with jQuery-UI, and these functions from the browser let the user stomp all over what I provide.

I've added the known fix to keep Firefox from dragging the image, so that takes care of part of the problem, but the resize handles still come up when you click the image and you can still resize it.

Is there a way to disable all of the image modification Firefox functions?

Answer (score 0):

Did you try attaching an event `onresizestart` to the image to `return false;` ?

It is worth trying I believe.

Note: I couldn't try out, as I don't have firefox here :(

Also, you can get all the images in your div and set the `contentEditable` property of each of those to `false`.

Sorry for too many edits